# How can I have a button trigger a function to move the mouse cursor on a timer in C#/visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm building an automatic timer system as a fun silly project for some office chums. It's end user goal is to allow end users to be away from keyboard while still simulating activity to prevent timed applications from changing their statuses to away.

I have the front end of a windows form with two buttons. ON and OFF. When I press on, I want it to begin moving the mouse in 1 minute intervals for a moment. (or click maybe.) and when I select off it stops the action.

I've never really coded much before (I've done basic python stuff so I know what an if statement is, a function, how to declare a variable etc but I've never done anything with a GUI or in c# so this is all new.)

Lastly, I would want to save/export it as an exe for distribution for slackers I mean end users to run and use.

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone is trying to hack their way out to keep their PC active when away from desk :D

```
//programmatically move the mouse example

PointConverter pc = new PointConverter();

Point pt = new Point();

pt = (Point)pc.ConvertFromString("0, 768");

Cursor.Position = pt;
```

[Ref](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7eeb890-a87d-4dbb-9ea8-a77ded3ee363/changing-the-mousecursor-position?forum=Vsexpressvcs)